# Find the largest values of $m$ and $n$ such that $24\ ^mC_n = \ ^{15}P_4$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The first thing I did was divide the $24$ to the other side to get $^mC_n =1365$, but I do not know what to do from there. The answer is $m=1365$ and $n=1364$.

Comment: You have a discrete function of *two* variables, so for any fixed $m$ there is a maximum $n$, and vice versa.  But your question as asked has no unique answer.  Analogy:  "What are the largest values of $m$ and $n$ such that $m+n = 10$?"

Comment: Your answer is just from 1365C1 = 1365. More interesting to find all the smaller pairs

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It might be reasonable to assume that $n\geq m/2$. In that case, a solution with a larger $m$ must also have a larger $n$.

Comment: @alex.jordan If that's indeed the constraint, even *THEN* there is no unique solution.  Analogy:  "What are the largest values of $m$ and $n$ such that $m + n = 100$?  You can assume $n \geq m/2$."

Comment: That analogy doesn't hold. As I said, with OP, if $m_1>m_2$, then $n_1>n_2$. That's not how it works with $m+n=100$. There is something special about $_mC_n$. Also, $m\leq1365$ because otherwise $_mC_n>1365$ or ${}=1$. So there is an upper bound.

Comment: @alex.jordan:  The core idea of the analogy *does* work.  If you place just a one-sided constraint (viz. $n \geq m/2$ or a maximum value) you *still* have *TWO* degrees of freedom... just with some restrictions.  You can place candidate solutions on a *TWO*-dimensional grid (with constraint boundaries)... and the fundamental problem remains.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That two-dimensional grid is a partially ordered set, with $(m_1,n_1)>(m_2,n_2)\iff (m_1>m_2 \text{ and } n_1>n_2)$. (The canonical partial ordering.) And among the finite collection of solutions in this question, there happens to be a maximal element according to that partial ordering. I just want to not put the brakes on the OP's question so quickly without thinking through the details that go with the given equation. It could be worded better for sure, instead of asking for "the largest values..." which I have to imagine a reasonable meaning for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $4! =24$. If we divide throughout by $24$, we get $^{15}C_4$ on RHS. So, $(m,n)\equiv (15, 4),(15, 11) $ is also a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can demonstrate that $m=1365$ and $n=1364$ is a solution.

If $m>1365$, then either $_mC_n=0$, $_mC_n=1$, or $_mC_n>1365$. So there is no solution with $m$ greater than the $m$ in your solution. So any solution has $m\leq1365$.

Any solution must have $n<m$. So if there is a solution where $n>1364$, then it has $m>1365$. But we established there is no such solution. So any solution has $n\leq1364$.

Since $(m,n)=(1365,1364)$ is indeed a solution, it is "the largest" be several reasonable meanings for "the largest".